# Showing a finite dimensional algebra over a field is semisimple via a characterization of the Jacobson radical

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

> Let R be a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra that has no elements $r \in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $rxr=0$ for all $x \in R$. Can it be determined whether $R$ is left semisimple from this information?

My thoughts:

I believe $_{R} R$ is indeed semisimple, though I don't have much more than a hunch at this point.

Since R is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, it is a left and right artinian ring, and a left and right noetherian ring: $_{R} R$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, and $R$-submodules are in particular $\mathbb{Q}$-vector subspaces, but no infinite chains of vector subspaces can exist in a finite dimensional vector space.

I am familiar with the fact that a ring R is left semisimple if and only if R is left artinian and the Jacobson radical is zero. I am also familiar with the fact that there are many equivalent characterizations of the Jacobson radical, so my hunch is that the given condition is related to one of these numerous characterizations.

Comment: Why do you believe that ${}_RR$ is semisimple? You do not seem to have any evidence for that!

Comment: @user the condition "$rxr=0$ for all $x\in R$ implies $r=0$" is equivalent to the ring having no nonzero nilpotent ideals. That is, it is semiprime. It's well-known that a semiprime right Artinian ring (like a finite dimensional algebra) is semisimple.

Comment: I see. Believe was a strong word. I had no evidence, just a feeling that the given condition said something about the Jacobson radical, but I was having trouble making the connection to the definitions I've just begun looking at. Thanks for answering anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the Jacobson radical $J$ is not zero. Since $J$ is nilpotent, there exists an $n\geq1$ such that $J^n\neq0$ and $J^{n+1}=0$. Pick any $r\in J^n\setminus0$.

If $x\in R$, then $rxr\in J^nRJ^n\subseteq J^{n+1}=0$.

Comment: (In particular, nothing uncommon is needed)

Comment: Indeed, I should have written unfamiliar (to me)! I'll change the title